# MySql Workbench SQL queries syntax errors

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm testing some simple scripts to get the feel of MySQL in Workbench. I've created a database called 'myschema' and am trying to execute the following script in the scripting shell

```
ALTER TABLE 'myschema'.'employee' DROP COLUMN 'date_of_birth' ;
```

However, I always get the following error:

Uncaught exception while executing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\scripts\deletion.py:
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\mysql\workbench\scripts\deletion.py", line 9

ALTER TABLE 'myschema'.'employee' DROP COLUMN 'date_of_birth' ;

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is a very basic command, so I'm confused as to why it's not working. **I've tried getting rid of the quotes and the 'myschema' part**, but I keep getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

In fact, I've found that no SQL queries at all work in the scripting shell. They all return syntax errors

SOLVED: I was using the wrong editor. Was solved by using the SQL Query Editor instead of the Scripting Shell

Comment: If you are in the database 'myschema' don't use myschema.employee,just use employee.Don't use quotes.Just give it as it is

Comment: As I said in my post, I've tried both of those changes and get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Remember than you should to use back quote for identifiers:

```
ALTER TABLE `myschema`.`employee` DROP COLUMN `date_of_birth` ;
```

Comment: I just made that change, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: MySQL is not Postgres. MySQL is not even normal when it comes to escaping identifiers.

Comment: Much better! Yeah, some days it's easy to cross the streams.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.employee DROP COLUMN date_of_birth;
```

or if you had non standard identifiers or reserved keywords to escape, you could use backticks:

```
ALTER TABLE `myschema`.`employee` DROP COLUMN `date_of_birth`;
```

Comment: The only reason you "must" escape is a conflict with a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and even then it's often contextual.

Comment: Like I said in my post, I've tried that (getting rid of the quotes). Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Bob can you post the describe for the employee table here?

Comment: @tadman - Agreed. I just mentioned it here for reference. Nothing more. :)

Comment: Yep! Just trying to add a bit more context. I see people escape all sorts of things out of unfounded paranoia, it borders on superstition, so a rational explanation helps defray that.

Comment: @Gurwinder In my database, called myschema, there is a table called employee. It has the attributes name, ID, and date_of_birth. ID is the primary key.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh How do I do that? Currently I'm running it from Scripting > Scripting Shell

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I'm using workbench right now. From workbench I go to Scripting > Scripting Shell

Comment: If it helps, I've found that no SQL statements are working in the Scripting Shell